# Temporary disable foreignkeys?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I saw thisone in MSDN magazine.i wanted to Temporary disable Foreignkeys,Can i do using following code.. Not needed to delete but temporary disable because i wanted to enable again

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT 
    FK_Orders_Customers
```

Answer (score 3):

-- Disable the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customers
```

-- Reenable the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customers
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as you've suspected `ALTER TABLE [table] CHECK / NOCHECK CONSTRAINT *FK_Name*` enables and disables foreign key constraint checking. It also proves why it is a good idea to explicitly name your constraints i.e. to avoid names like `FK__TABLE__A2A64E930CBAE877`.

One point to note that after inserting / changing data with disabled foreign key constraints is that SQL won't trust your constraint if you simply enable it with CHECK CONSTRAINT. You will need to do the following to get SQL to recheck the constraint during re enable:

```
ALTER TABLE [table] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT *FK_Name*
```

You can check for violations with

```
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS ([table])
```

Ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456(v=sql.90).aspx (Disabling Constraints) and also see http://geekswithblogs.net/dturner/archive/2011/01/31/sql-constraints-check-and-nocheck.aspx